# random.sample produces 'sample larger than population, python 3.3

Tags: tkinter

i am writing a piece of code that should read a list of 10 words from a text file then randomly choose 9. The problem faced is my code (below) produces an error stating 'sample larger than population'. Could anyone help? thanks.

```
with open("9 words.txt") as f:
    for r in range(3):
        words = random.sample([x.rstrip() for x in f],3)
        grid = [words[i:i +3] for i in range(0,len(words),3)]
        for x,y,z in grid:
                Label(text=(x,y,z),font = font).grid(row=r)
```

The error is stated in the 3rd line down.

Comment: print this line `[x.rstrip() for x in f]` and see if you are not getting just one item

Comment: i get an 'invalid syntax' error. with the code i have, the program displays 3 of the words but then states the error in question @StevenSummers

Comment: Ah, it needed brackets for the print statement. it prints all 10 words in a list format - square parenthesis @StevenSummers.

Comment: I can only believe it to be your file. I tested your exact same code substituting f as a list of 10 strings and it worked fine. There were 10 items in the printed list weren't there?

Comment: The text file is set out like this (copied from file)                                       NIGHT
SMOKE
GHOST
TOOTH
ABOUT
CAMEL
BROWN
FUNNY
CHAIR
PRICE but the files is set out vertically so one line has one word - also, sorry for the late reply, had to go out. @StevenSummers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the problem, but I'm not entirely sure what was actually causing it. You need to assign the list comprehension outside the for loop.

```
with open("9 words.txt") as f:
word_list = [x.rstrip() for x in f] # Assign here
for r in range(3):
    #word_list = [x.rstrip() for x in f] # Remove from main code only example
    #print(word_list)  # Remove from main code only example
    words = random.sample(word_list, 3)
    grid = [words[i:i +3] for i in range(0,len(words),3)]
    for x,y,z in grid:
            tk.Label(text=(x,y,z)).grid(row=r)
```

As you'll see from the output of print if you uncomment the lines.

```
['NIGHT', 'SMOKE', 'GHOST', 'TOOTH', 'ABOUT', 'CAMEL', 'BROWN', 'FUNNY', 'CHAIR', 'PRICE']
[]
#Error
```

So for some reason it was emptying the list

Comment: what do you mean by list comprehension? And what should i assign on the second line? @stevenSummers

Comment: this `[x.rstrip() for x in f]` is list comprehension. By assign I mean, store the value as `word_list` also you can remove comments, they were just to show how error was occurring.

Comment: The code you have given seems to empty the list completely when printed, as if the code emptied the txt file like nothing was in there? is there possibly an alternative to random.sample as i feel this may be the issue? Thanks @StevenSummers